Does a character with Nourishing Gate need to feed their Undead Hunger?
I'll be playing a Blood Lords campaign soon and I was wondering if a ghoul kineticist with the level 14 feat Nourishing Gate would still need to feed their Undead Hunger?

Nourishing Gate says (in part):

You don't need to breathe, eat, or sleep...

Ghouls normally eat. The effect of the Nourishing Gate feat is that they no longer need to eat. What they normally eat is irrelevant.

Is there anything in "blood lords" campaign which would make ghoul eating more than just nourishment? It is somehow related to their undeadness, after all, which is more than just "nourishment", although how that works in detail is not part of standard rules, just hinted at in the ghoul description. And regular PF undead are immune to effects of starvation anyway.

@NeilSlater That sounds to me like another question - though you might open up to ask whether there is any lore about this. :)
